# Fake pathlib.Path in class variable using pyfakefs'

Tags: python, pyfakefs

I have a class variable of type `pathlib.Path`.

```py
from pathlib import Path


class MyClass:
    FILE_PATH = Path('/etc/ids.json')
```

I know that *pyfakefs* is not able to mock this automatically. So in my test I use its `Patcher` class (I also tried other ways.) to reload the corresponding module.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher
from pyfakefs.fake_pathlib import FakePathlibModule

from . import my_class


def test_class_variable(fs):
    # my_class.MyClass.FILE_PATH = Path('/etc/ids.json')
    with Patcher(modules_to_reload=[my_class]):
        assert type(my_class.MyClass.FILE_PATH) is FakePathlibModule.PosixPath
```

But it still isn't mocked.

If I uncomment the commented line, the test succeeds.

What should I do to mock the class variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you create the patcher twice: once via the `fs` fixture, and once manually via the `Patcher` instantiation.

`pyfakefs` does not support nested filesystem mocks - in case of nesting it just uses the existing one. This is somewhat described [in the caution about module- and session-scoped fixtures](https://pytest-pyfakefs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#class-module-and-session-scoped-fixtures), but probably needs a more prominent place in the documentation, as this is true independent of the usage of module or session-scoped fixtures.

The easiest way to fix this is to just omit the `fs` fixture here:

```py
def test_class_variable():
    with Patcher(modules_to_reload=[my_class]):
        assert type(my_class.MyClass.FILE_PATH) is FakePathlibModule.PosixPath
```

If you need this more than once (or if you don't want that setup in the test itself), you can instead create your own fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fs():
    with Patcher(modules_to_reload=[my_class]) as p:
        yield p.fs


def test_class_variable(my_fs):
    assert type(my_class.MyClass.FILE_PATH) is FakePathlibModule.PosixPath
```

*Disclaimer*:
I'm a maintainer of `pyfakefs`.

*Update*:
A added [a chapter about nested fake filesystems](https://pytest-pyfakefs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#nested-patcher-invocation) to the troubleshouting guide.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I think it's even nicer without the implicit fs fixture. Some of my colleagues were confused where this comes from.